# How to show that the special orthochronus pseudo orthogonal group is the connected component of the identiy?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, connectedness, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathbb{R}^{t,s}$ be the the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{t+s}$ equipped with the non degenerate indefinite scalar product $\eta$ that satisfies:

$$\eta(e_i,e_i)=-1\text{ for $1\leq i\leq t$}\qquad \eta(e_i,e_i)=1\text{ for $t+1\leq i\leq s+t$}$$
and:
$$\eta(e_i,e_j)=0\text{ for }i\neq j$$
Then the Pseudo Orthogonal group is the Lie group defined by the set
$$O(t,s)=\{A\in GL_{s+t}(\mathbb{R}):A\eta A^T=\eta\}$$
The special pseudo orthogonal group is given by:
$$SO(t,s)=\{A\in O(t,s):\det(A)=1\}$$
Examine the subspaces $V_-$ and $V_+$ spanned by $\{e_1,\dots,e_t\}$ and $\{e_{t+1},e_{t+s}\}$ respectively. We say that $A\in O(t,s)$ preserves the time orientation of $\mathbb{R}^{t,s}$ if and only if $A|_{V_-}$ is and orientation preserving isomorphism onto its image. One can check that this then implies that if $A$ is written as the block matrix:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
A_{tt}&A_{ts}\\
A_{ts}&A_{ss}
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $A_{ij}$ is an $i$ by $j$ matrix that $A$ preserves the time orientation if and only if $\det(A_{tt})>0$. We thus define the  special orthochronus pseudo orthogonal group as:
$$SO^+(t,s)=\{A\in SO(t,s):\det(A_{tt})>0\}$$
Apparently, this is the connected component of the identity. I have zero idea how to show this thought. In the Euclidean norm case I can use the face that as smooth manifolds:
$$SO(n)/SO(n-1)\cong S^{n-1}$$
and proceed by induction since $SO(2)\cong S^1$ and $SO(1)=\{1\}$. I would ideally like to do something similar here, by looking at the level set $\eta^{-1}(1)$, and then somehow argue that isotropy group of any $p\in\eta^{-1}(1)$ is some other $SO^(t',s')$ such that $t'<t$ and $s'<s$, but I can't see the path forward.

I guess one could also show that as manifolds $SO^+(t,s)\cong SO(t)\times SO(s)\times\mathbb{R}^{rs}$ but this feels like a large endeavor for a small result.

Is there perhaps a way to show this directly?

Comment: Look up Lemma 6 on page 237 of O'Neill's *Semi-Riemannian Geometry With Applications to Relativity*. While he doesn't use quotients explicitly, it is a (half-page) proof by induction where $\eta^{-1}(1)$ is the protagonist.

Comment: @IvoTerek thanks for the source. this is what I needed.